# Conditional Formatting using Left and Right

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting, vba

I am trying to perform Conditional Formatting for a group of cells based on each cells value. In each cell I have "X (Y)" such that X and Y are integers. It is formed by using the Concatenate formula and grabs values from elsewhere in my workbook. I need to perform some conditional formatting that says the following:

```
If Y > 0, then highlight green
If Y < 0, then highlight red
If Y = 0, then highlight blue (or no highlight)
```

I solved the negative issue by just checking to see if a cell contained a "-", but the other two I am stuck on. I have tried using the search function to search for "(0)", but the formula only applies to the first cell I have. I have tried using Left and Right to check for the greater than 0 part, but excel doesn't like it.

I think the issue might be because of relative/absolute cells, but I do not know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

no, X and Y are parts of a string, not integers, convert them though while grabbing the part of that string: (don't try with right however, you have a parenthesis there)

```
Int(Left()) and Int(Mid())
```

Comment: You are right, X and Y are strings. I meant to say when the value is displayed they are integers. I used your method and it worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this without using conditional formatting. Highlight your cells and apply custom formatting (right click > format cells > number > custom) and use something like this as your custom number string:

```
0[green];0[red];0[blue]
```

Comment: I tried to do it this way and excel corrected to to be [green]0;[red]0;[blue]0. In short it didn't work, but you did say use something like what you had above. I am not the best with the custom format, but thank you.